# How to convert this code from angular1 to angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

there,
i want use **ng-class="{active: isOpen()}"** in angular 2,
but i don't know  ,how to convert this code from angular1 to angular2,
any one help me?
thank you very much.
my code from there:http://www.theme-guys.com/materialism/angular/#/apps/todo

```js
app.directive('menuToggle', ['$location', function($location) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      name: '@',
      icon: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'assets/tpl/directives/menu-toggle.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      icon = attrs.icon;
      if ( icon ) {
        element.children().first().prepend('<i class="' + icon + '"></i>&nbsp;');
      }

      element.children().first().on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        link = angular.element(e.currentTarget);

        if( link.hasClass('active') ) {
          link.removeClass('active');
        } else {
          link.addClass('active');
        }
      });

      element.find('a').ripples();

      scope.isOpen = function() {
        folder = '/' + $location.path().split('/')[1];
        return folder == attrs.path;
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
 
<li menu-link="" href="#/" class="ng-isolate-scope">
          <a ng-transclude="" ng-class="{active: isOpen()}" href="#/ui-elements/cards" class=""><span class="ng-scope">Cards</span><div class="ripple-wrapper"></div></a>
        </li>
```

Comment: Please show your research efforts and attempts to do this yourself. SO isn't a code conversion service but you will get help if you show you have made an effort to resolve problem yourself

Comment: Read http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/09/migrating-directives-to-angular-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"How to convert this code from angular1 to angular2?"

3 easy steps:

1- You go into this page:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

2- You try to do it yourself.

3- If you have any specific questions (questions, not free work requests) you go to http://stackoverflow.com and ask them there.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert  `ng-class="{active: isOpen()}"` in angular 2 the syntax would be

```
[ngClass]="{active: isOpen()}"
```

active is the css class and isOpen() should be a function in your typescript component.