# How do you upgrade bindings when converting an Angular 1 directive into an Angular 2 component?

Tags: angularjs, angular

In Angular 1, you have binding declarations in directives using '@', '=' and '&' symbols.

In the new Angular 2 component, I think that the bound variables become class member variables decorated with @Input() but what do you do about these differences in binding type when you're converting the directive into a component?

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHZOu_n5M0Q) youtube video where he just eliminates the binding type symbol ('=') altogether. Is it that easy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert this code from angular1 to angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828511/how-to-convert-this-code-from-angular1-to-angular2)

Comment: I guess they are questions along the same journey. This one is pretty narrow and just about the binding types. The other question is more of a request for some code to be translated.